# in-app purchase queryInventoryAsync doesnt return item which is already purchased

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, nokiax

I am using test Product Id  `(PRODUCT_ID = "1023608")` to implement Nokia In-App purchase.

I can successfully purchase an Item using following code snippet.

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, PRODUCT_ID, RC_REQUEST, this, "");
```

I am getting succes response in `onIabPurchaseFinished`.

When I try to query recent purchases using `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(this);` I am getting `Owned items response: 0`.

I was just wondering It should return me the product Id of purchased item.

Can anybody please help me If I am missing anything ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using emulator for testing: Then the known issues would state that "**State of test IDs is not stored to back-end when emulator is used to initiate the purchase transactions.**"

Here's link to it: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Nokia_X_known_issues

Comment: Jukka Sir I am testing it on Nokia X device.

Comment: Ok, then I need to ping some help outside the site and see what goes on there.

Comment: @Jukka I am using Test Id.Is this reason queryInventoryAsync doesn't show it as purchased ? 2nd point mentions that I guess in document.

Comment: I asked help from NIAP expert, could indeed be the point, but then it should be made more clear in the documentation indeed.

Comment: Jukka Thanks :-) I have also published one sample app on Nokia store with In App item.One it is approved I will test the app using actual product id.

Comment: I got reply from an expert, and the issue is as you expected, also already added to docs, will then be available on next refresh

Answer (score 1):

You need to give productBundle as parameter to getPurchases-call. That Bundle should containt products related to your app:

```
ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
products.add("1023608");
products.add("1023609");
products.add("1023610");

Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();
queryBundle.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", products);

Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, queryBundle, continueToken);
```

Note that test product ids are not working with getPurchases.

Comment: Note that there is also alternative way to give those products by using setProductMappings-method. (see link: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/nokia-in-app-payment/nokia-in-app-payment-porting-guide.html). If you use that method, you should not give that queryBundle for getPurchases.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply.I have done exactly same way you have shown above.What I am thinking currently is getPurchases might not work with test product Ids.

Comment: That is correct. Test product Ids does not work with getPurchases.